# OnItemSelectedListener is an interface but how to instantiate directly?

Tags: android

in the below code they are instantiating the `OnItemSelectedListener` directly inside `setOnItemSelectedListener()` method but it is an interface how the following code works fine explain anyone please...

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelected: " +parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: look for Anonymous (inner) classes

Answer (score 1):

" `new OnItemSelectedListener()` " will create an object of that interface, and this object is we are using in `spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener()`

Its similar to :

```
OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelected: " +parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

because its Anonymous Class.

1. Anonymous class is declared and initialized simultaneously.
2. Anonymous class must extend or implement to one and only one class or interface resp.
3. As anonymouse class has no name, it can be used only once.

eg:

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used spinner in adapter to get start time so here is my code, just implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener than:

((ViewHolder) viewHolder).startTimeSpinner.setTag(R.id.startTimeSpinner, viewHolder);

((ViewHolder) viewHolder).startTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (parent.getId()) {

        case R.id.startTimeSpinner:
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) parent.getTag(R.id.startTimeSpinner);
            mFromSelectedItemPosition = holder.startTimeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            mFromSelectedTime = holder.startTimeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            mFromAmPmSelectedItem = holder.startTimeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
    }
}
```